# Cameras Services documentation missing?

Tags: camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI,

Are photo/SetConfig , photo/GetConfig and photo/Capture
at http://wiki.ros.org/Sensors/Cameras#Services still valid with kinetic and on?
Or are the links just broken?

Any pointers appreaciated.

Thanks, -Ville

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264349/cameras-services-documentation-missing?/) by [vilvo](https://answers.ros.org/users/30842/vilvo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-06-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In a way, yes. The documentation for those services can actually be found [here](http://docs.ros.org/groovy/api/photo/html/index-msg.html).

However, following the various links leads me to [wiki.ros.org/photo](http://wiki.ros.org/photo), part of (what was then still called) the `bosch_drivers` stack.

I'm not sure how generic those services are, and if they were ever used by nodes other than `photo_node`. The wiki doesn't show any users of the package (no *Used By*), and `photo` itself does not seem to have been maintained/released since Groovy.

If you're interested because of `photo/Capture`: polled topics were never really implemented ([REP 106](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0106.html)), but there is the [polled_camera](http://wiki.ros.org/polled_camera) package.

As for the `GetConfig` and `SetConfig` services: I guess most drivers migrated to `dynamic_reconfigure` or implemented their own custom service API.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1